# Casting to a reader or creating a new reader

Tags: java, casting, bufferedreader

I am a little bit confused by the following thing:

```
public randomConstructor(Reader r) {
    this.bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(r);
}
```

It seem to be logical that if you want to use a BufferedReader you should create one and use the reader as a parameter. However, I saw something like that:

```
public randomConstructor(Reader r) {
    this.bufferedreader = (BufferedReader) r;
}
```

Obivously it doesn't work if r isn't a BufferedReader itself.

Sorry if I can't give you any better example, but I can remember that there was an example where it actually made sense to cast it to a reader. Is there any exception where it does make sense?

EDIT: bufferedreader is obviously a private variable of the type "BufferedReader" :)

Comment: Casting in this case is rather dangerous, since you're opening yourself up to a `ClassCastException`.  If you know you're going to need a `BufferedReader`, you're always better off making the parameter type reflect that, or create one yourself, like you do in your first example.

Comment: @azurefrog I see, so at the end of the day it is just a silly idea, right?

Comment: @DennisvonEich A. A `Reader` must not be a `BufferedReader`, and B. You should not have a constructor with a read once object (like Streams). Better use a Source to read from.

Comment: This would only make sense if the author of the code "knew" the incoming `Reader` was always a `BufferedReader`. It would work up until that condition didn't hold, and then you'd get a `ClassCastException`.  This is severe code smell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performing an unchecked cast is always dangerous and should be avoided.

The first constructor is a good example use of a pattern called the [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). The `BufferedReader` decorates the passed in `Reader` object. If you are designing a class that will take in any kind of `Reader`, and there are many, you can easily wrap that reader with the `BufferedReader` and get the benefits of buffering with the benefits of a polymorphic constructor.

The only case where it *might* make sense is if the incoming constructor is already a `BufferedReader`. Wrapping it with another `BufferedReader` probably isn't necessary. In that case, you could perform an `instanceof` check like the following:

```
public randomConstructor(Reader r) {
    if (r instanceof BufferedReader) {
        this.bufferedreader = (BufferedReader) r;
    } else {
        this.bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(r);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could also provide an overridden constructor which expects a `BufferedReader` in addition to the one that expects a `Reader`.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled and couldn't find a scenario in which you know that `r` is of type `BufferedReader` but still have a good reason to pass it as a `Reader`.

What would make more sense (to me) is to have the second version modified to:

```
public randomConstructor(Reader r) {
    if (r instanceof BufferedReader) {
        this.bufferedreader = (BufferedReader) r;
    }
    else {
        this.bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(r);
    }
}
```